# Meteor facebook id vs accounts id

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am making an application which uses both the accounts package and facebook's graph api. Specifically the friends api. The friends api returns all facebook friends that have used the application. The problem is that it returns facebook id's, and the accounts package generate application specific id's. This is problematic when i want to retrieve information from a collection containing a friends information, but stored with the application specific id. I have worked around this by storing both the fb id and the accounts id in the collection.

But i still can't update a user data based on their fb id, as update is only permitted using the application specific id. What i want, but not allowed:

```
UserData.update({fbId: friend.fbId},{$push: {some: data}});
```

The only solution i could think of is to get each user id first, like this:

```
var friendId = UserData.findOne({fbId: friend.fbId})._id;
```

This is obviously not a good solution as it needs one extra db call for every update.

Is there a way of setting the accounts id equal to the facebook id upon creation? Or do you have any other suggestions.

Comment: Is `UserData` a custom collection? If you're updating the Meteor.users collection, What's the error you get when you update?

Comment: @Xinzz UserData is a custom collection. If try updating with fbId I get the following error: `Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending on the comment above:

> MoeRum: @Xinzz UserData is a custom collection. If try updating with fbId I get the
>   following error: Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may
>   only update documents by ID. [403]

That is because you're trying to update on the client-side. You can only update by ID on the client-side. What you're trying to do should not be a problem as long as you do it on the server.

From the Meteor docs (for more reference: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/update):

> The behavior of update differs depending on whether it is called by
>   trusted or untrusted code. Trusted code includes server code and
>   method code. Untrusted code includes client-side code such as event
>   handlers and a browser's JavaScript console.
>
> - Trusted code can modify multiple documents at once by setting multi to
>     true, and can use an arbitrary Mongo selector to find the documents to
>     modify. It bypasses any access control rules set up by allow and deny.
>     The number of affected documents will be returned from the update call
>     if you don't pass a callback.
> - Untrusted code can only modify a single document at once, specified by
>     its _id. The modification is allowed only after checking any
>     applicable allow and deny rules. The number of affected documents will
>     be returned to the callback. Untrusted code cannot perform upserts,
>     except in insecure mode.